# Django Rest Framework viewset - ForeignKey filtering filter based on Username Issue

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django project and i have integrated the Django Rest Framework into the project for the back end. I have a Profile model. In the profile model, I have a user foreignkey that has a username field. The username is what I am currently using for filtering profiles.

I had everything working perfectly when the `ListAPIView` and `RetrieveAPIView` were seperated.

```
class ProfileListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

class ProfileDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.queryset.get(user__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

Another thing is that when the views were seperated, I set a username parameter in the url that was passed into the view. I am not sure how to integrrate that into viewsets.

```
path('users/', UserListView.as_view()),
path('users/<username>', UserDetailView.as_view()),
```

this is what it I have now

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename='user')
router.register(r'profiles', ProfileViewSet, basename='profile')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

I am trying to change my code so that rather than each view sperate I want to use a generic view set that is a single point with all views.

When I use look at the API in my web browser, the list view works but when I try to search a specific username, I get an error.

```
DoesNotExist at /api/users/profiles/omarjandali/
Profile matching query does not exist.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/api/users/profiles/omarjandali/
Django Version: 2.1.5
Exception Type: DoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Profile matching query does not exist.
Exception Location: /Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 399
Python Executable:  /Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.2
Python Path:    
['/Users/omarjandali/Documents/splittapp/backend/src',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python3.7',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/omarjandali/anaconda3/envs/splittapp/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 23 Jan 2019 03:21:44 +0000
```

Comment: your problem in `self.queryset.get(user__username=self.kwargs.get('username')) `. This error tell us cant get any match with this query. Can you show value in `self.kwargs.get('username')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that viewsets have what is called a `lookup_field` inherited from the `GenericAPIView`. It is essentially a field used to retrieve a single object in the detail endpoint of the viewset. By default, it is usually the id field so it tries to search a profile with `id=omarjandali` but of course that does not exist as that is a username.

So if you want to use username instead of ids for lookups, you have to specify the `lookup_field` as username. So you should have something like this:

```
class MyViewSet(vieswts.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    lookup_field = 'user__username'
    ...
```

Bear in mind that this means you can no longer retrieve profiles by their `id`.

To allow more complex lookups using more than one lookup field, you have to override the `get_object()` method and implement the logic there.

For this, you can use this mixin I built and use in my projects.

```
class AlternateLookupFieldsMixin(object):
"""
Looks up objects for detail endpoints using alternate
lookup fields assigned in `alternate_lookup_fields` apart
from the default lookup_field. Only unique fields should be used
else Http404 is raised if multiple objects are found
"""

alternate_lookup_fields = []

def get_object(self):
    try:
        return super().get_object()
    except Http404:
        lookup_url_kwarg = self.lookup_url_kwarg or self.lookup_field
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        obj = None
        for lookup_field in self.alternate_lookup_fields:
            filter_kwargs = {lookup_field: self.kwargs[lookup_url_kwarg]}
            try:
                obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
            except Http404:
                pass
        if obj:
            self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
            return obj
        raise Http404
```

**How to use it:**

Add the mixin to your viewsets and specify the extra fields to be used for lookups in the `alternate_lookup_fields` list. This means that you can(most likely should) allow the original `lookup_field` to be id and add extra lookup fields in the list.

Please bear in mind that you should only use unique fields for lookups, else you will run into issues where multiple objects are found.

So, in your case, using the mixin will look like this:

```
class MyViewSet(AlternateLookupFieldsMixin, vieswts.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    alternate_lookup_fields = ['user__username']
    ...
```

Comment: Would I need to make any changes to the urls for the view set to make sure that it knows a username is being passed through.

Comment: No, the viewset already defines a permisive kwarg regex for the pk. It accepts a wide range of values including usernames

Comment: Here is a small question. So I have a model that has a user foreign key. There can be several account model records for each user. when I add a username at the end of a url, I want it to filter out the accounts with that user foreignkey. MORE THAN ! RECORD RETURNED is throwing back and error. I used `    def get_object(self):
        return self.queryset.get(user__username=self.kwargs.get('username'))` to filter it and had to use a second list view,

Comment: That is the warning I added to my answer if you did read it. Never use a non-unique field for lookups like this. If many accounts can be connected to the same user, then don't use the user's username for lookups. You need to use a field that is assured to return just one single object each time

Comment: What you want to do on a non-unique field is filtering and not lookup. This means you will just filter using the list view for all accounts connected to that user. Check django-filter and DRF docs on how to implement filtering. If you run into another issue, post a different question for it as they're different things. Since this answered your original question, don't forget to accept and upvote. Goodluck!